# Python Regex Check for Credit Cards

Tags: python, regex

I created a script to look for specific card numbers, of which, are included in the list credit_cards. Simple function, it just marks each one as Valid/Invalid depending on the regex pattern listed.

My problem stems from understanding how to implement this regex check, with the inclusion of spaces, and periods. So if a card were to have 3423.3423.2343.3433 or perhaps 3323 3223 442 3234. I do include hyphens as a delimiter I'm checking for, but how can I also include multiple delimeters, like periods and spaces?

Here is my script-

```
import re

credit_cards = ['6011346728478930','5465625879615786','5711424424442444',
    '5000-2368-7954-3214', '4444444444444444', '5331625879615786', '5770625879615786',
    '5750625879615786', '575455879615786']

def World_BINS(credit_cards):
    valid_BINS = r"^5(?:465|331|000|[0-9]{2})(-?\d{4}){3}$"

    do_not_repeat = r"((\d)-?(?!(-?\2){3})){16}"

    filters = valid_BINS, do_not_repeat

    for num in credit_cards:
        if all(re.match(f, num) for f in filters):
            print(f"{num} is Valid")
        else:
            print (f"{num} is invalid")


World_BINS(credit_cards)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question. Are you trying to match some specific card patterns (e.g. the 4 starting digits) or only be able to include spaces and periods in your regex?

Comment: Right- so the script currently looks for hyphens along with the specific pattern of numbers only. I'm trying to figure out how to add periods and spaces to that list of possibilites, much like the addition of hyphens. If I were to take out the line looking for any potential hyphens, it won't match, despite the cc number including the 4 digits I'm looking for

Comment: I think you need `valid_BINS = r"^5(?:465|331|000|[0-9]{2})(?=([\s.-]?))(\1\d{4}){3}$"` and `do_not_repeat = r"^((\d)([\s.-]?)(?!(\3?\2){3})){16}$"`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew you are an absolute legend. Hadn't thought of adding it in like that! Thank you!

Comment: You could apply a more rigorous test by checking to see if the card number is consistent with the [Luhn algorithm](https://allwin-raju-12.medium.com/credit-card-number-validation-using-luhns-algorithm-in-python-c0ed2fac6234).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
credit_cards = ['5000 2368 7954 3214','5000.2368.7954.3214','6011346728478930','5465625879615786', '5711424424442444', '5000-2368-7954-3214', '4444444444444444', '5331625879615786', '5770625879615786','5750625879615786', '575455879615786']

def World_BINS(credit_cards):
    valid_BINS = r"^5(?:465|331|000|[0-9]{2})(?=([\s.-]?))(\1\d{4}){3}$"
    do_not_repeat = r"^((\d)([\s.-]?)(?!(\3?\2){3})){16}$"

    filters = [valid_BINS, do_not_repeat]

    for num in credit_cards:
        if all(re.match(f, num) for f in filters):
            print(f"{num} is Valid")
        else:
            print (f"{num} is invalid")


World_BINS(credit_cards)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lV0NfC).

The `(?=([\s.-]?))(\1\d{4}){3}` in the first regex captures a whitespace (`\s`), `.` or `-` as an optional char into Group 1 and then `\1` refers to the value (either an empty string, or whitespace, or `.` or `-`) in the next group. The lookaround is used to make sure the delimiters / separators are used consistently in the string.

In the second regex, `^((\d)([\s.-]?)(?!(\3?\2){3})){16}$`, similar technique is used, the whitespace, `.` or `-` is captured into Group 3, and the char is optionally matched inside the subsequent quantified group to refer to the same value.

Comment: This is perfect- thanks for the awesome explanation!